# Checkboxes disappearing on hover in Firefox for Mac with show-hide input options

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox

I have found what I believe is a browser-related quirk, but I need to find a way to work around it.

Please navigate to http://darkspin.com/users/jeremy/Information%20Request%20(with%20checkbox%20behavior).htm in Firefox for Mac (latest public version), expand all the checkboxes, and then scrub over them with your mouse. You will see various checkboxes disappear and then not re-appear until you toggle the checkboxes being shown or not. This has not been seen in any other browsers, and looking through Firebug I see no changes or errors occurring.

The show/hide behavior is jquery-powered. Please keep in mind that this is built on top of a form generator where I am unable to change the underlying HTML.

If you have any thoughts, please let me know!

Comment: Your link isn't responding for me - a jsfiddle would also do the trick if it's possible.

Comment: Link works for me, but I don't have a Mac to test on.

Comment: I can confirm seeing the same result in Firefox 23.0.1 and 24.0 on Mac OS 10.8.5 at that URL. Not all checkboxes disappear but many of them do. The boxes will reappear if you take focus off the browser. You can still click on them when they are invisible and when they appear again you can see that they have been successfully checked. I have the exact same issue on a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is present only in old version of Firefox for Mac, if anyone else stumbles upon it (not sure which versions specifically). Update FF if possible. The fix is to add padding/margin/spacing between checkbox inputs if that isn't possible.